# Camera slider issue

Tags: javascript, responsive-slides

I have a website with OpenCart. The slider is called 'camera by pixedelic.com' and I've tried to make that responsive. I saw in a javascript file an option to do that:

```
 *mobileEasing      : 'yes',    //leave empty if you want to display the same easing on mobile devices and on desktop etc.*
```

This does not work. I've pasted the code for camera.css here - http://pastebin.com/a7QpQhur and the camera.js here - pastebin.com/mBFuYj2F.

The images show up as larger than expected with width and height set in style=".." and simple width=".." and height="..".  And here is the HTML Structure - http://pastebin.com/YU9k4Rri

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: Please try to elaborate on what you expect to see here.

Comment: i want to make him responsive..

Comment: I don't understand what that means though. Explain what you mean by responsive in this context. Do you mean respond to mouse-overs, clicks, etc? And what behavior do you expect to see: Image changes size, moves, etc?